# video streaming and displaying simultaneously in android

Tags: android

Please provide some url related to some documentation about video streaming in android. I got many document on this site but all are getting total content of video from url and then playing the video but i want to stream and play video simultaneously so that i can play without consuming a lot of time. thank you

Comment: please explain how you achieve you goal, means file downloading and playing, i want to implement in android, actually my requirement is similar to your's. Please help. i was open below suggested link but that is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two techniques:

1. Using MediaPlayer: If you are using streaming server to fetch video then just provide your URL in MediaPlayer source. MediaPlayer will manage everything.
2. Manually: If you are not using streaming server for video then you need to download and play video. Use following link as example. In following link author explain audio streaming. You can use same technique for video.

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/

Comment: Hey KPBird, this is link not working, can you please send other link for same problem.

Comment: Hello Ram - check this link http://www.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/